# Скрыть div по id

Tags: javascript

На странице есть несколько блоков div с классами `trading__buy-nav` и каждый блок имеет уникальный id. Если один этих дивов активен, то к нему добавляется класс acive, получается `trading__buy-nav active` Как можно сделать, чтобы если какой-то определенный див активен(определенность определяет его id), то скрываются другие блоки, с другим классом и тоже с уникальным айди. Т.е есть 2 блока

```
<div class="trading__buy-nav active"name="odin" type="radio" id="CoinVal_1" checked="checked" onclick='CoinValChange("CoinVal_1");' />1</div>
<div class="trading__buy-nav" name="odin" type="radio" id="CoinVal_2" onclick='CoinValChange("CoinVal_2");' />2</div>
```

Если активен первый блок с id CoinVal_1, то нужно скрыть 2 блока

```
<div class="trading__market-table-row" id="CoinProd_1" name="CoinID_1" onclick='ChangeCoinProdBuySell("CoinID_1");'>
<div class="trading__market-table-row" id="CoinProd_2" name="CoinID_2" onclick='ChangeCoinProdBuySell("CoinID_2");'>
```

Если же активен 2ой блок, то скрыть таких же 2 блока, но с другими id

Comment: Есть стойкое ощущение, что задачка решается совсем не так, как надо) Сюда бы минимальную разметку... которая ответила бы на вопросы - для чего и кого надо скрывать, есть ли закономерности между активными и скрываемыми, и о каком количестве элементов идет речь)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME    я так понимаю мне нужен селектор по нескольким атрибутам, делаю так, чтобы не переписывать кучу строк кода. Если говорить о количестве элементов, то при активности одного класса, нужно скрыть 2 других

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME можете помочь?

Comment: минимальный воспроизводимый пример приложите, пожалуйста, ничего не понятно, что-то мудрите

Comment: Не совсем понятна проблема: вам надо получить список всех элементов с id или технологию скрытия/показа элемента по классу "active"? По какому событию будет меняться показ? Вот пример без id, с классом active - с установленным класом элемент показываем, с убранным скрываем: https://codepen.io/ilya-lokalin/pen/qBBgWjB

Comment: @ИльяЛокалин если блок с id "abc" активен, то скрыть 2 блока с id "111" и "222". Если же активен блок с id "zzz", то скрыть 2 других блока  c id "333" и "444"

Comment: @meine изменил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Есть необходимость логически все связать и описать зависимость имен id и связанных с ними групп элементов. Так же надо выбрать алгоритм скрытия/отображения. Вот что-то вроде базового варианта.

**Управление**
У вас есть управляющие элементы от которых вы берете состояние и на которые весите прослушивание событий. Если два верхних элемента в вашем примере чекбоксы (тег div у чекбокса заменить на input) то состояние лучше взять через checked.
**Отображение**
Есть элементы для отображения информации - показывать/скрывать их удобно через класс active. В CSS прописываете соответствующие свойства (display block/none иди visibility hidden/visible). Элемент с классом 'active' - показываем, без класса скрываем.
По событию onClick на чекбоксе по выбранному алгоритму на элементы отображения функция добавляет класс 'active' или убирает его. Для этого можно использовать:

```
element.classList.add('active')
element.classList.remove('active')
element.classList.toggle('active')
```

В примеры скрытия/отображения добавил чекбоксы: https://codepen.io/ilya-lokalin/pen/qBBgWjB

**Алгоритм**
Вам необходимо решить что будет происходить по событию и сделать набросок последовательности возможных событий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- событие onClick скрывает/показывает логически связанные элементы (как на рисунке выше) - каждый чекбокс работает как переключатель для своей группы элементов;
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- одна группа скрывается, другая отображается - тут подойдет настройка инпутов как радиокнопок. Во включенном состоянии может быть только одна группа элементов.

**Важно.**
Теперь, чтобы более конкретно ответить на ваш вопрос, необходимо знать предполагаемый вами алгоритм и зависимость элементов отображения от управляющих элементов. Берете вы уже готовый проект, с организованной структурой или делаете новый.  
И если есть возможность избежать использование ID, лучше их не использовать. События можно повесить на классы, отображать тоже по состоянию классов.